# ETH: How many transactions are added to the mining pool per time period

Tags: mining-pools, statistics

Every ETH transaction which is created is first added to a pool of pending transactions, from which then the miners pick them. I wonder whether there is any source (research paper / ETH stats website / etc.) or a way to figure out how many ETH transactions are added to the pool per time period (either day/minute/second)?

Answer (score 0):

There are statistics for that. Here is one: https://etherscan.io/chart/tx

Basically you just record how many different transactions your node hears of. All transactions are broadcast to all nodes so you should hear of all of them - at least in theory.

As an extra detail: there is no explicit "pool" of transactions. It's just an abstract construct which means the amount of transactions which nodes are aware of but haven't been mined yet.

Comment: Lauri, thanks a lot for your answer! However, isn't this chart showing just how many transactions per day are added to the blockchain? I was looking for the number of transactions that are broadcasted per day, which includes those that will eventually end up in the blockchain, those that the miners will never pick (very low fees etc) or even the malfunctioned ones. Or maybe this chart is already showing all of them? Many thanks!

Comment: Well you know as much as I do - I just read what it says. I really can't say which one is correct, I just assumed it was all txs but can't say for sure